# SimpleXMLElement Object

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

When I do `print_r($nodes);` I get:

```
Array (
  [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
    [kategoria_6] => 1
    [opis_6] => 1
    [img] => slides/slide0.jpg
  )
  [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
    [kategoria_6] => 2
    [opis_6] => 2
    [img] => slides/slide1.jpg
  )
  [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
    [kategoria_6] => 3
    [opis_6] => 3
    [img] => slides/slide4.jpg
  )
  [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
    [kategoria_6] => 4
    [opis_6] => 4
    [img] => slides/slide3.jpg
  )
  [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
    [kategoria_6] => 7
    [opis_6] => 7
    [img] => slides/slide2.jpg
  )
)
```

And now in this case, I can't do this:

```
$nodes->asXML("c:\\aaa.xml");
```

because this is an array i could do f.ex:

```
$nodes[1]->asXML("c:\\aaa.xml");
```

but I'll get only one element. I need to get all of this array, or better change it to this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object (
  [item] => Array (
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
      [kategoria_6] => 1
      [opis_6] => 1
      [img] => slides/slide0.jpg
    )
    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
      [kategoria_6] => 2
      [opis_6] => 2
      [img] => slides/slide1.jpg
    )
    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
      [kategoria_6] => 3
      [opis_6] => 3
      [img] => slides/slide4.jpg
    )
    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
      [kategoria_6] => 4
      [opis_6] => 4
      [img] => slides/slide3.jpg
    )
    [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
      [kategoria_6] => 7
      [opis_6] => 7
      [img] => slides/slide2.jpg
    )
  )
)
```

How do solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, SimpleXML by itself does not easily allow you to do what you want to do. Luckily, [DOM](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) does (**FIXED**):

```
// Create a new DOMDocument
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');

// Create the DocumentElement
$documentElement = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('objects'));

// Loop the SimpleXML elements and import them into DOM
foreach ($val as $element) {
  $documentElement->appendChild($dom->importNode(dom_import_simplexml($element), TRUE));
}

// Save to file
$dom->save("c:\\aaa.xml");
```

Comment: Not working, something is wrong in line: $dom->documentElement->appendChild(dom_import_simplexml($element));

Comment: @ariel What error are you getting?