# XML sorting in PHP

Tags: php, xml, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SimpleXMLElement Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685139/simplexmlelement-object)

Hi I want to sort an XML document - I do it like this:

```
public function xsort(&$nodes, $child_name, $order=SORT_ASC)
{
    $sort_proxy = array();

    foreach($nodes as $k => $node) {
        $sort_proxy[$k] = (string) $node->$child_name;
    }

    array_multisort($sort_proxy, $order, $nodes);

}
```

And I get sorted array in `$nodes` variable. In code it is used in this way:

```
$this->xsort($nodes, 'kategoria_6', SORT_DESC);
```

When I do print_r($nodes); I get sorted view

```
SimpleXMLElement Object (
  [kategoria_6] => kat4 
  [opis_6] => opis4 
  [img] => slides/slide3.jpg
) 
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
  [kategoria_6] => kat3 
  [opis_6] => opis3 
  [img] => slides/slide2.jpg 
) 
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
  [kategoria_6] => kat2 
  [opis_6] => opis2 
  [img] => slides/slide1.jpg 
) 
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
  [kategoria_6] => kat1 
  [opis_6] => opis1 
  [img] => slides/slide0.jpg 
) 
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
  [kategoria_6] => kat1 
  [opis_6] => opis1 
  [img] => slides/slide4.jpg 
)
```

But when I want to save it into a file, it is unsorted. File saving code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
foreach ($nodes as $element) {
    $dom = dom_import_simplexml($element)->ownerDocument;
}
$dom->save("c:\\aaa.xml");
```

Does anyone know why it is saving unsorted?

Comment: @DaveRandom I'm surprised no one flagged it as a duplicate or voted to close it as a duplicate. Since it is a duplicate, I'll close it. Thanks for the heads up.